# Focus on the tank (CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, scroll

i have a little tank game: http://develope.games:8082/ , the arena is bigger than the browser window. When the tank is driving out of the window i can scroll with the scrollbars to keep the tank in view. How can i do this scrolling automatically? The tank should always be on focus.

Answer (score 1):

Overall you have 2 options:

1. If your game view is designed like a camera in any engine, you can set the camera to move with the tank as long as you have "more" screen to the sides.
2. When the tank reaches the middle of the screen, you change the movement from the tank to the environment for as long as you have "more" screen to the driving side, when the screen is "over" you change the movement back to the tank.

hope was helpful